# Adding a 'warp' feature to cocos2d / box2d game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision-detection

I am having trouble getting a "warp" feature to work correctly in a cocos2d / box2d game.

I have two items for my main sprite to collide with - and if the sprite collides / enters one, then it exits the other - like a warp or teleport feature.

The problem I have is that if my sprite collides with "A", I then move it's position to "B" and it should exit "B" and keep going with the same direction and speed that it had before the "A" collision.

But as soon as the sprite hits "B", it is seen as a collision with "B" and it jumps back to "A"!

So if my sprite hits either warp feature, it ends up stuck in an endless loop where it just continually jumps from A to B and back again!!

I have tried a lot of temporary fixes, such as adding, eg, (x+10) to the position, so that it clears the "B" collision when it exits B, but that is a messy solution.

Hoping someone might have another bright idea!!

Comment: How about just making note of the fact that the next collision with B should be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a BOOL to keep track of your collision state?

So when your object collides with A, set

```
_isColliding = YES
```

Once you're free of collisions, set

```
_isColliding = NO
```

Any collisions that happen while _isColliding is still set to YES would be ignored.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, and it seems to work ok!